# Creating a click event off of a jquery created html class in jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to create a class with an on click event, then revert the changes by clicking a different click event. Like a toggle with two different buttons.

```
$('.detail-click').on("click", function() {
$(this).parent().css('height','400px');
$(this).parent().html('<img class="exit" src="img/exit.png">');
});


$('.exit').on("click", function() {
$(this).parent().css('height','88.390625px');
});
```

the exit class is performing no action, I need it to change the size of its parent. Eventually I would like to have the exit class remove itself and revert changes.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are registering events for the elements which are not available during page load you have to use [**`event-delegation`**](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) to make the concept working,

```
$(document).on('click','.exit' ,function() {
   $(this).parent().css('height','88.390625px');
});
```